# Nividia Compute Visual Profiler options grayed out

Tags: cuda

When I analyze a kernel of mine, following buttons are grayed out in the Kernel Level Analysis:

- Limiting Factor Identification,
- Memory Throughput Analysis and
- Instruction Throughput Analysis.

... while Occupancy Analysis is activated.

Is this behavior due to my old gpu (Quadro FX 580 with CC 1.1.) or due to me having set the wrong checkboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be due to either -- older GPUs don't have the same built-in counters, which means that the data can't be collected from them.  I normally check *all* the boxes for a specific run, then see what I get.  I uncheck boxes as necessary for further tests.

Comment: I don't know, if it is new, or I missed it before, but now there is an message at top of the Kernel Level Analysis window: `Note: Some analysis features are disabled because they are not supported on device having compute capability less than 2.0 or required options are not available.`